# Clone a virtualenv without use pip freeze

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I'm working with a virtualenviroment that don't have a downloads for some modules, so doing `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and then `pip install -r requirements.txt` won't work. There's a way to avoid this?? 
After that, I have to copy this virtualenv inside another machine, so maybe there are some PATH to change or something else, right?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a source control tool like git, an install script, or a combination of both. Keep the install script in your top level directory and run it on the new machine. Use `curl` to download what you need into the proper directory.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to install latest Django.

1. Download the .gz file from pypi.python.org locally somewhere and unzip it. You should have setup.py file visible.
2. Now either activate your virtualenv and go to the Django folder where you see setup.py and type command `python setup.py install`.
3. Or grab the full path of python binary/executable in your virtualenv and go to the folder where you have the setup.py and do `your-complete-path/python setup.py install`

Answer (score 0):

One tool that helps copying / moving virtualenvs is [virtualenv tools](https://github.com/fireteam/virtualenv-tools).  Since you've tagged [python-3.x], here's a python3.x compatible fork: https://github.com/Yelp/virtualenv-tools

When moving / copying a virtualenv, several files contain information about the original path and need to be updated (notably shebangs of scripts, pyc files, etc.)

One would invoke virtualenv tools as follows:

```
virtualenv venv
venv/bin/pip install ...
venv/bin/python -m virtualenv_tools --update-path $REMOTE_PATH venv
# Then you can package up `venv` and ship it to other boxes, and put it at /$REMOTE_PATH on disk
```

Disclaimer: I partially maintain the 3.x fork